# Counting words per line from text file in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def getInputFile ():
bad = True
while bad:
    try:
        fileName = input ("Enter file name: ")
        # Open file for input
        f = open(fileName, "r") # Note: "r" means open for reading.
        bad = False
    except Exception as err:
        print ("Please enter a valid file name:")
return f


lines=0
wordCount=0
fileHandler=getInputFile()


for lineOfText in fileHandler.readlines():
    lines += 1
    print(str(lines),str(lineOfText))
    f1=lineOfText.split()
    wordCount=wordCount+len(f1)
    print ("Word count:" +str(wordCount))
```

Currently, my program counts only the running total of words in the text file but I want it to just count the words in each line of the file. Also I would like the program to analyze the text file at the end and print out things such as "most words in a line" and "average words per line" but I can't do that with my current format. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are doing cumulative addition `wordCount=wordCount+len(f1)` .. of course you will get total at the end

Comment: Also see: [Counting lines, words, and characters within a text file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783899/counting-lines-words-and-characters-within-a-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just need to add a couple things:

```
lines=0
wordCount=0
mostWordsInLine = 0
fileHandler=getInputFile()


for lineOfText in fileHandler.readlines():
    lines += 1
    print(str(lines),str(lineOfText))
    f1=lineOfText.split()
    wordCount=wordCount+len(f1)
    if len(f1) > mostWordsInLine:
        mostWordsInLine = len(f1)
    print ("Word count:" +str(wordCount))

print "Average words per line: {}".format(wordCount / lines)
print "Most words in a single line: {}".format(mostWordsInLine)
```

EDIT: To print out the # of words in each line, you can change the `print` statement inside the `for` loop.

Currently you're doing `print ("Word count:" +str(wordCount))`, which prints out the cumulative total. Simply change this to `print 'Word count: {}'.format(len(f1))`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not able to count the words in each line; it is still just keeping a cumulative total.

Comment: @AButler - If you want to keep a record of the word count in each line, you'd be better off with a solution like the one in my answer below.

Comment: @AButler Edited the response to address that case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `list` out of it:

```
result = [len(line.split()) for line in fileHandler]
```

Then you can find the total word count:

```
print(sum(result))
```

The word count for each line:

```
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

The highest word count:

```
print(max(result))
```

The average word count:

```
print(sum(result) / len(result))
```

If you also want to save each line, read it first:

```
lines = fileHandler.readlines()
```

Then count the words:

```
result = [len(line.split()) for line in lines]
```

Then `zip()` these two `list`s:

```
print(*('{} -- {}'.format(*item) for item in zip(lines, results)), sep='\n')
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. Would there be any way for me to print the word count for each line after printing out each line?

Comment: @AButler - You should save the file contents as well, then, as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: since `split` splits on whitespace by default, that won't count exactly words. For example `some - sentence` will result in a length of 3.

Comment: The rules for counting words are, in a word, complex. They are also somewhat arbitrary, with different implementations having different definitions of what constitutes a word. `split()` may be naive and basic, but it's easy to use and understand. Better word counting methods are not in the scope of a question like this.