# How to determine the lines, and how many words in my song using split() in python

Tags: python-3.7, strsplit

Music lyrics

Look what you made me do, I'm with somebody new
Ohh, baby, baby, I'm dancing with a stranger

#### I tried using re.split also tried loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting lines, words, and characters within a text file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783899/counting-lines-words-and-characters-within-a-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, you should always post your code with the question. Anyway, .split() works fine, I would count lines by counting the number of newline characters '\n'

```py
s = "Look what you made me do, I'm with somebody new Ohh, baby, baby, I'm dancing with a stranger"
lines = s.count('\n')
lst = s.replace('\n', '').split()
words = len(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lyric = "Look what you made me do, I'm with somebody new Ohh, baby, baby, I'm dancing with a stranger"
print(len(lyric.split()))
```

This splits each word into an element of a list and prints the length of the list which is equal to the number of words in the song.