# Taking words that I have in a list and searching for them within a Text File and getting a count for each word

Tags: python

I am learning Python and currently I have a text file. Within that text file, I want to search for the words I already have within a list ['mice', parrot'] and get a count of how many times mice and parrot have been mentioned. I currently have.

```
enter code herewith open('animalpoem.txt', 'r') as animalpoemfile:
data = animalpoemfile.read()
search animals = ['mice', parrot']
```

Comment: You might find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783899/counting-lines-words-and-characters-within-a-text-file-using-python?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To count the number of occurrences of a specific word in a text file, read the content of text file to a string and use String.count() function with the word passed as argument to the count() function.**

Syntax:

```
n = String.count(word)
```

where word is the string, and count() returns the number of occurrences of word in this String.

So you can read the file and make use of count() method.

```
#get file object reference to the file
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    #read content of file to string
    data = file.read()

words = ['apple', 'orange']

for word in words:
    print('{} occurred {} times.'.format(word, data.count(word)))
```

Hopefully, this should work fine.

Note:
You can even loop through each and every word and increment the counter. But using a high-level programming language like Python, it would be beneficial to make use of such built-in methods.

Answer (score 0):

An example solution:

```
import re

animals = ['mice', 'parrot']

# make a dictionary with keys being the names of the animals,
# and values being initial counts (0)
counts = dict([(a, 0) for a in animals])

with open("animalpoem.txt") as f:
     for line in f:  # loop over lines of the file, assign to variable "line"
          for word in re.findall("\w+", line.lower()):  # convert to lower case and make list of words and then iterate over it
               if word in counts:  # tests if the word is one of the keys in the dictionary
                    counts[word] += 1  # if so, increments the count value associated with that word

print(counts)
```

`animalpoem.txt`

```
Three blind mice. Three blind mice.
See how they run. See how they run.
They all ran after the farmer's wife,
Who cut off their tails with a carving knife,
Did you ever see such a sight in your life,
As three blind mice?
```

Program output:

```
{'mice': 3, 'parrot': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

steps

1. open file
2. read file and store in a variable
3. count the word you want to search for in this variable

   ```
   def num_of_word_in_file(file_name, word):
     with open(file_name) as file:
       content = file.read()
     return content.count(word)
   for animal in animals :
       print(num_of_word_in_file(file_name, animal))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Counter()` method from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('t.txt', 'r') as animalpoemfile:
    dct = Counter(animalpoemfile.read().split())

search_animals = ['mice', 'parrot']
    
for animal in search_animals:
    print(animal, dct[animal])
```